# UITableView "separatorStyle" behavior in ipad and iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

```
_studentListTableView.separatorStyle =UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
_studentListTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Above code working fine in iPhone but in **iPad**, more space showing in left and right side margins shown in below screenshot is it default behavior in iPad? also have used SeparatorInset for tableview is UIEdgeInsetsZero though left side showing more space.

---

Here green color is tableview, red color is separator color, gray color is cell color

[ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkX3W.jpg)

---

Why this behavior happens in iPad?

> Note: In iPhone it is working fine.

Below is the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" code

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student %li",(long)indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you using iOS9? There actually exists some tricks in TableView in iOS9.

In iOS 9, UITableView's cell auto margins to "Readable Content", this may cause the space margin.

To avoid this, just set **tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO**

Comment: By the way, you may create as much cell objects as your data objects. It isn't good to make reuseIdentifier bases on the indexpath.A reuse identifier is used to identify **a specific kind** Cell.In your case, a @"studentCell" string(or any other) would be fine.